# how to link website to google+ so that profile picture appears in searches

Tags: search, seo, google-plus

I used

```
<link rel="author" href="https://plus.google.com/113756..7573388>
```

in the head of my page. Then I put the address of my page in the contributor section of my google+ account. 
Now when I go to richsnippets tool it says Error: Author profile page does not have an authorship link to a Google Profile.

What should I do more so that the picture of my profile to appear in searches?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1)** Create a link to your Google+ profile from your webpage, like this:

```
<a href="[profile_url]?rel=author">Google</a>
```

Replace [profile_url] with your Google+ profile URL, like this:

```
<a href="https://plus.google.com/109412257237874861202?rel=author">Some Anchor Text</a>
```

**2)** Add a reciprocal link back from your G+ profile to the site(s) you just updated.

The instructions are here, see option 2:

http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1408986&expand=option2

Check with the Structured Data Testing Tool:

```
http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets
```

Google makes it pretty clear that they don't guarantee your G+ avatar will appear in SERPs even if you have correctly established authorship; there's no guarantee.